# Keyboard Crushing TextFields

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm learning to code in Flutter and and redoing one of my Android/iOS apps.  This is roughly what the UI looks like so far:

[image]

When I tap a field to open the keyboard, it smashes all of the fields together.

[image]

I'm trying to decide what the best way of handling this is.  The only way I can think of to fix it is to somehow not have all of the fields and the button pushed up when the keyboard opens.  But if I do that, then the fields lower on the screen will not be visible when data is being entered into them.  Is there a good way to handle this?

This is the code for this view:

```
class _CarbCalcState extends State<CarbCalc> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carb Calculator'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple.shade700,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            NutrientValue(
              nutrientName: 'Protein',
              onChanged: (value) {
                print('Protein Changed');
              },
            ),
            NutrientValue(
              nutrientName: 'Fat',
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            NutrientValue(
              nutrientName: 'Fiber',
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            NutrientValue(
              nutrientName: 'Moisture',
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            NutrientValue(
              nutrientName: 'Ash',
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.blue.shade700,
                child: Text(
                  'Calculate Carbs',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NutrientValue extends StatelessWidget {
  NutrientValue({@required this.nutrientName, @required this.onChanged});

  final String nutrientName;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 90,
          child: Text(
            nutrientName,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
              signed: false,
              decimal: true,
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
            onChanged: this.onChanged,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter $nutrientName',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a Column with several Expanded inside which take care that the space is evenly distributed. When the space shrinks by the keyboard, they move together. Basically it is a good idea to put input fields into a Scrollview because of the Keyboard. You can use SingleChildScrollView with your Column but you need to replace the Expanded widgets with a Container for example or just use the plain TextFields.